# Oracle regex expression containing "?"

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query that uses regex expression as follows

```
UPDATE user_master SET first_name = ? WHEREuser_id = NVL(Regexp_substr(?, '^(\[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\[0-9]*)?)$'), 0)
```

For this query to execute I have available GUI interface with me where I can pass required values seperated by `,`

```
field_value_1
field_value_2
```

Here it got error like

```
Count of fields selected does not match the count of place holders in sql for update section
```

Here it is expecting `three field values` since total number of `?` are `three` (two of them as place holder and one is within `regex`) .

How to make this functionality intact while ignoring `?` within `regex`

Comment: What kind of GUI is it ? Homemade ? External ?

Comment: it is external and cannot be controlled by me

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you replace `'^(\[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\[0-9]*)?)$'` with  `'^(\[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\[0-9]*)' || chr(63) || ')$'` ?

It's ugly but it may be the only way to trick your badly written GUI tool.